# How to extend Indonesian visa on arrival (VOA) in Indonesia

Tags: visas, eu-citizens, visas-on-arrival, indonesia, visa-extensions

What is the best way to extend visa on arrival in Indonesia? I will have 30 days visa on arrival (25 USD) and I need more 30 days without leaving country. It's possible to extend visa right after you get VOA?

Comment: Which country do you hold a citizenship of?

Comment: I'm citizen of Czech Republic (European Union).

Comment: agrred but for the purpose of apply ing visa at local spot they need clearance from immigration office from indonesia, now its again one more trouble for me not like other country like singPore its easy, i tried website of imigration office for this clearance letter , i even email them but not reply from there side, i still confused for wht to do, i wana cheaper way to extend the visa , one way is to fly to nearest airport n come back. but its still expensive thanks.

Comment: Hi @sukesh, I've converted this to a comment for now as it wasn't a real answer to his question.  It sounds like you're having problems with visas too? Perhaps raise a new question and the community would be happy to try and help you too!

Comment: You might just want to directly get a 60 days tourist visa from an Indonesian embassy. You can do it in person at the one in Singapore as I explained in this question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48200/how-to-get-a-60-days-indonesian-tourist-visa-from-singapore

Comment: The best resource I came across in the last few weeks on the "Indonesian Visa Extension" topic, incredibly useful & detailed http://www.lashworldtour.com/2013/09/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-tourist-or-social-visa.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have never tried to get my visa extended in Indonesia. Take this is a disclaimer, then, for this what I know from a mix of personal experience and what I've heard from other travellers.

A lot of fanfare was made in 2009-2010 when it was announced that VOAs would be made extendable. Technically, the visa-on-arrival is extendable for 30 days in addition to the initial 30 days by visiting a local immigration office - as the [Indonesian Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.kemlu.go.id/Pages/ServiceDisplay.aspx?IDP=7&IDP2=21&Name=ConsularService&l=en) states. However, the [Embassy of Indonesia in UK website makes adds a note](http://www.indonesianembassy.org.uk/consular/consular_visa_type_arrival.html):

> Please be advised that Visa On Arrival may only be extended upon
>   approval from the Director General of Immigration of the Republic of
>   Indonesia **in case of natural disaster, illnes [sic] or accident**, but
>   cannot be transferred to another type of visa.

The official website of the Indonesian Tourism Board [also states the same](http://www.indonesia.travel/en/frequently-asked-questions/). On searching online, it appears other people like [this guy](http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Extend-a-Visa-on-Arrival-%28VOA%29-In-Indonesia&id=4058455) - who has an Indonesian wife - could list her as a sponsor and got the visa extended. Others, however, weren't as successful (search Lonely Planet's Thorn Tree).

To further confuse matters, my Indonesian VOA stamps all state 'Valid for 1 time only. **Not extendable**.' There aren't multiple categories of VOA, as far as I know, so I don't know why it says this.

My advice would be that it's just a lot less hassle to get a 60-day tourist visa by applying at your local embassy / consulate. The less you have to deal with local *Imigrasi* - from what I've heard of experiences from other travellers there - the better for you.

It will probably be cheaper for you too. For VOA, they accept payments in US dollars and Indonesian rupiah. The first time I went to Indonesia I made the mistake of not carrying any USD, only rupiah. The published rate for visa fees in rupiah turns out to be around $3-4 higher - so I ended up paying more. You'll pay in rupiah at local immigration offices for the extension which means you'll get the same lousy exchange rate instead of the $25. So paying for the 60-day tourist visa in your own country (roughly $45, depending on country) is going to be cheaper, not to mention less hassle compared to getting it in Indonesia.

Comment: It seems like you can also simply renew the visa after arrival in about 1 week. You can do it yourself (deal with the Indonesian administration & transport to get there) or simply ask a local travel agency to do it for you. These guys from StartUpTakeOff explain more in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSbhRH9ERPQ