# What is the process of extending a single entry Indonesian visa while in country?

Tags: visas, legal, passports, australian-citizens, indonesia

A friend of mine is in Indonesia and attempted to get an extension to his single entry visa a day before it was due to expire, instead of an extension he was given a receipt to replace his passport(Australian).

Exact text of his FB post:

> Ok, strangest thing I've had to do in Indonesia is hand my passport to
>   some guy to get an extension on my visa because the Immigration
>   officer told me they couldn't do anything because my visa ends
>   tomorrow. Now I have a little receipt replacing my passport. Oh gosh

Is this the normal procedure?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-on-arrival-voa-in-indonesia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They returned to the immigration office asked some questions and apparently the receipt tells them to come back on Thursday (4 days time) to collect their passports.

Comment: lol. yeah, seems rather a normal procedure. It seems like this process usually takes about 1 week. You can do it yourself (deal with the Indonesian administration & transport to get there) or simply ask a local travel agency to do it for you (the simplest/worry-less option). These guys from StartUpTakeOff explain more in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSbhRH9ERPQ