# Timeframe for extension of Indonesian 60 days tourist visa

Tags: visas, indonesia, tourist-visas

How soon can I apply for a one month extension of my Indonesian 60 days tourist visa?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is NO time limitation in when to apply for a one month extension of a 60 days tourist visa.

I myself applied for such extension several weeks before the end of my visa. This process can take up to 2 weeks so make sure you apply **at least 2 weeks before the end of your visa**.

I wrote a complete guide on how to do this on this question [How to extend Indonesian 60 days tourist visa in 2015?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49778/9395)

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly comprehensive guide on how to do this at the [Lash World Tour](http://www.lashworldtour.com/2013/09/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-tourist-or-social-visa.html), which is too long to copy here but the key point is:

> **You need a sponsor for Tourist and Social Visa extensions**

And there is a related question on this site as well:

- [How to extend Indonesian visa on arrival (VOA) in Indonesia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-on-arrival-voa-in-indonesia)

Comment: 60 days tourist visa are NOT visas issued on arrival. The link to that SO question is then irrelevant. The first link to lash world tour is excellent though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply at least 3 working days before it ends.

It is not a written rule. In fact, as far as I know, it is not a written rule that you can extend a tourist visa (if you ask in 5 different immigration office, you will get 2 to the power of 5 answers)

So I suggest you don't push your luck and do it one week in advance.

Comment: That's not true. I extended my 60 days tourist visa several weeks before it ended. The process takes up to 2 weeks so actually, you'd better not wait too long!

Comment: Sorry, I meant "at least 3 days". The time it really take depend on which office you are going (plus a blind luck component). In Medan and Bandung, it usually take 2 days. In Jepara, they usually take 3 weeks. I love Indonesian immigration -__-